# rsync to ONLY keep files in destination that have been removed from source

Tags: rsync

We use rsync to copy filesystem contents from one machine to another as a backup.
We first run MACHINE-X->MACHINE-Y rsync for a straight backup with the --delete and --delete-excluded switches
We also run an internal Rsync between the MACHINE-Y destination, and another folder on MACHINE-Y with either of the delete flags. This maintains a non-destructive copy in the event someone inadvertently deletes a file on MACHINE-X. However, it also has the overhead of being a complete copy of what has already been synchronized.

Ideally I want to be able to run the non-destructive rsync in such a way that the destination ONLY receives the deleted files and so avoids unnecessary duplication . Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `-i --dry-run` to get the list of changes between your two folders and then only keep the files that have been deleted.

However, most people do backups with `rsync` by first doing `rsync` and then `cp -al` of the backed up data (e.g. `current`) into a different directory (e.g. `archive`). The `-l` argument tells `cp` to not copy the data but to just create a hardlink. That way, you have the same data available under `current` and `archive`, but every file occupies the disk space only once (e.g. without the overhead you are experiencing now).

Later, as soon as you again `rsync` your server to `current`, `rsync` will update the all the files that have changed and delete the files that have been deleted. The files in `archive`, however, will not be touched.

Of course, you can create as many `archive` folders as you want. Also note that `rsync` offers the `--link-dest` option, which can automatically create the `archive` folder during the `rsync` run, without having to run `cp -al`. See the man page for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simpler:

```
find dir1 | ssh host2 " \
  cat > tmpfile1 ; \
  find dir2 > tmpfile2 ; \
  join -a1 tmpfile1 tmpfile2 | \
  xargs rm -rf ; \
  rm tmpfile1 tmpfile2"
```

At least this is plain shell without rsync...

Comment: Careful. This may fail quite badly in the presence of filenames containing spaces.